# black and white photos on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, photos.app, third-party

I started clicking some black and white photos (monochrome) using the iPhone.

1. I would like to see them in a separate folder, is there some setting provided by iOS to do so?
2. If there is no such option supported by iOS, that is, by the default Photos app , are there any third-party apps (available on Apple App Store) that can find and show ONLY the monochrome images i have taken.
3. If no such app exists, how can i get started with making such an app? Any libraries that will save my time and avoid reinventing the wheel?

I hope photos clicked using the Camera are labelled/categorized with such information in EXIF or somewhere else (like a list of files in the library stored on device with such attributes) so that writing an app would be easier and less time-taking as compared to loading every image and checking if the pixel patterns fits that of a monochrome image. (imagine checking thousands of photos)

Comment: Have you tried searching for "Black and White"? I know it's not a great solution, but it could work to identify them and put them in folders manually.

Comment: @Andre yes, that didn't help. searching using that query resulted in zero relevant results.

Comment: Sadly, there doesn't appear to be an EXIF tag that indicates monochrome. Some lack the ColorSpace EXIF tag, but it seems like it happens with all filters, even color filters.